# Problem passing information from react tag to method within google maps api

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, google-earth

I am creating a map using the google maps api. One of the features that I want to include is a google earth style street view when the user selects a marker. Here is the tag I include that allows for the google earth map to be displayed:

```
        <Street
          latlng={{
            lat: selected.geometry.coordinates[1],
            lng: selected.geometry.coordinates[0]
          }}
        />
      )}
```

Here is the actual street method that I have included that displays the google earth box:

```
function Street(latlng){
  const streetViewPanoramaOptions = {
      position: {lat: latlng.lat, lng: latlng.lng},
      pov: {heading: 100, pitch: 0},
      zoom: 1
    };
    // }
  return(
    <div>
        <h2>
                <div style={{
                    width: '400px',
                    height: '200px',
                    backgroundColor: '#eeeeee'
                }}>
                    <ReactStreetview
                        apiKey={"MY API KEY"}
                        streetViewPanoramaOptions={streetViewPanoramaOptions}
                        onPositionChanged={position => this.setState({position: position})}
                        onPovChanged={pov => this.setState({pov: pov})}
                    />
                </div>
        </h2>
            </div>
  );
}
```

Unfortunately, but not unsurprisingly, this does work. When I run that the google earth map just displays a black screen. I am pretty sure the cause of that is that latlng.lat and latlng.lng don't have any values assigned to them. So my question is, how would I get data from the tag (where I assigned the lat and lng variables) to the method?

Comment: Can you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of your code so far that shows the issue? You can put it in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/).